# Random file from folder (no repetition)

Tags: php, random, directory

So I'm using the following code to pull a random file from a folder and I would like to make it so there is never a chance of pulling up the current file again (ie: seeing the same image/document twice in a row).

How would I go about this? Thanks in advance!

```
function random_file($dir = 'destinations')
{
    $files = glob($dir . '/*.*');
    $file = array_rand($files);
    return $files[$file];
}
```

Comment: Your question is ambiguous... Do you simply mean you don't want to see it twice in a row, or do you really never want to see the file again, ever?

Comment: Do you mean in a single request? or should it be persisted between requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the last viewed filename in a cookie or in the session.

Here's how to do it with a cookie:

```
function random_file($dir = 'destinations') {
    $files = glob($dir . '/*.*');
    if (!$files) return false;
    $files = array_diff($files, array(@$_COOKIE['last_file']));
    $file = array_rand($files);
    setcookie('last_file', $files[$file]);
    return $files[$file];
}
```

Comment: That appears to have worked perfectly! Are there any downsides to using a cookie?

Comment: The "headers already sent" error means that you have already printed something to the browser before the call to setcookie(). You can either call random_file() before you start printing things, or you can use a session variable, like `$_SESSION['last_file']` instead of `setcookie()` and `$_COOKIE['last_file']`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$picker = new FilePicker();
$picker->randomFile();
$picker->randomFile(); // never the same as the previous
```

--

```
class FilePicker
{
    private $lastFile;

    public function randomFile($dir = 'destinations')
    {
        $files = glob($dir . '/*.*');

        do {
            $file = array_rand($files);
        } while ($this->lastFile == $file);

        $this->lastFile = $file;

        return $files[$file];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially: store the name of every file used in an array; every time you pull a new name, check whether it already exists in the array.

[`in_array()`](http://www.php.net/in_array) will help you with that. [`array_push()`](http://www.php.net/array_push) will help fill the "used files" array.

You could make the array a [static](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) one to have the list available whenever you call the function (instead of using global variables).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to present a fixed set of files in random order, 
then read all file names into an array, shuffle the array
and then just use the array from start to end.

Comment: I'd rather avoid having to enter them into an array as it might become too tedious if there are a lot of files.

Comment: Eh? Read the file names with readdir. But anyway, since you were fine with "no repetitions", then its sufficient to just remember the last file.